# Excel help - if keyword exists in a column for each row

Tags: excel

I need help to check if a user has "Basic" in another column (Doesn't need to be same row) and return true in column D.

It seems I need to do some concatenation with index match but I do not know how to go about it. Can anyone help?

```
Col_A    Col_B    Co_C         Col_D
UserA    Data1    Basic        True
UserB    Data2    Premium      False
UserC    Data1    Basic        True
UserA     Data2   Classic      True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,A2,$C$2:$C$5,"Basic")>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

or

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=A2)*($C$2:$C$5="Basic")),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: @Wanderer - Because `UserA` has `Basic` in `Cell C2` all the occurrences of `UserA` should be `TRUE`, If I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Perfect.. worked exactly what I wanted. Where onI vote for as complete?

Comment: Mark the post as the answer as explained in the [Tour]